# Who is this size-shifter that gets smarter as he shrinks

Tags: comics, character-identification, super-hero

I remember this character from a superhero comic book. It was almost certainly a book by a US publisher, and I'm pretty sure it was not older than late 90s.

I'm also pretty sure that the character in question is male. His super power is that he can change his size at will. The interesting twist here was that his intelligence is directly tied to his size: At normal size he is of average intelligence, but the more he shrinks, the smarter he gets, and conversely, he gets dumber as he grows bigger.

This made for an interesting trade-off in physical strength vs. intellectual capacity. It also makes it dangerous for him to grow very big, as he is always at risk of losing control as an effect of his fading intellect.

Comment: This sounds really familiar, but I can't place it...

Comment: Yeah I think I know this one. Who’s the cat that won’t cop out when there’s danger all about... wait, no, wrong one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like [Maul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maul_(Wildstorm)) the Image character.  It's usually expressed as him getting dumber the bigger he gets.

> Maul has the ability to grow in size and mass at will. As he grows larger, Maul's strength and durability grow accordingly. Maul at his largest size can lift 100 tons plus. A side effect of the growth is that Maul's intelligence inversely diminishes the larger he becomes. This can work the other way around as Maul can diminish his size and mass to boost his already considerable intellect. As a part of the WildCats, Maul has been trained in combat by his teammate Spartan.

Comment: That's the one. There are some great characters in the Wildstorm universe. It's a shame they have been pretty much forgotten these days.

Answer (score 1):

The character Ben Teneson from the show 'Ben 10', didn't get dumber as he got larger, but did have a very small hyper intelligent character he could morph into.

Basically, the show is about a boy who gets an alien watch locked on his arm. There are 10 transformations he can effect, hence the 10 in 'Ben 10' with it also be a play on the Ten in Teneson.

The show revolved around bad aliens trying to get the watch from him and attacking different places that Ben had to protect using the different forms. A lot of the shows had the watch glitching or him accidentally picking the wrong character in his eagerness, so he'd end up as the hyper intelligent character when he actually meant to be the speedster.

Each character on the watch that he could turn into was actually a real species of alien. The smallest was also hyper intelligent. This maybe who you're remembering.

Answer (score -3):

Power man?
the thunderbolts and a few other evil things.
sounds right. Was in the defenders?
powers match.

Comment: You should add some more details to flesh out why you think Power Man is the right character